# Imageview - a small problem

Tags: android, layout, size

My problem is that i have placed an ImageView and 6 TextViews as below in a relative layout...

```
-------------  ----------  ---------
|           |  |txtview1|  |txtview2|
| ImageView |  ----------  ---------
|           |  |txtview3|  |txtview4|
|           |  ----------  ---------
|           |  |txtview5|  |txtview6|
|           |  ----------  ---------
-------------
```

but the problem is that i have set the imageview as wrap_content... and unless i set a size for it... it doesnt show up... is there any special specification needed 4 setting image style?

Comment: Can you post your layout XML: that would help a lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `Layout weight = 1`